# A word or succinct phrase for "capable of producing financial income"

Tags: synonyms

I have a bullet point list describing some requirements for a game I will be producing. It is written as follows:

The game will be:

- Requirement 1
- Requirement 2
  ...

One of the requirements is "capable of producing financial income", but this is a bit of a mouthful.

At the moment I have the word "monetizable", but that is a bit of a miserable little word. Are there any better suggestions?

Comment: What are you trying to say?

Comment: Maybe *profitable*?

Comment: Instead of monetizable. *Able to be monetized*.

Comment: Has it come to this? Business requirements for a game must include the proviso that the project must actually *make money?* Profitable is the correct word. Don't overcomplicate things.

Comment: How about just plain old **ka-ching!**? ;-)

Comment: @ghoppe: Yes, and that's a serious answer. Because there are other cases. Some games are developed to showcase particular technology, such as a new feature on a videocard or a 3D engine that's available for licensing. Such games tend to feature a lot of eye candy, but are typically on the short side. For instance, X-Isle: Dinosaur Island by CryTek (shows NVidia's GeForce 3 at work)

Comment: Thats funny. I'm in similar quandary. "Monetizable" is the word I want but it sounds awful - or so I feel. Unfortunately, "generate new revenue streams" sounds equally awful.

Comment: Is the question about producing **some** revenue (as opposed to not producing any revenue at all), or about producing **profit** (net financial gain)? The question, as formulated, seems to be about the former, but most of the comments and the answers on this page ignore the difference between the two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with "monetizable". Some dictionaries haven't yet caught up with the now-widespread usage, but it's a perfectly regular extension from...

> [**monetize**](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/monetize#English) (verb) *To make a business activity profit-generating, **particularly in computer and internet-related activities.*** [emphasis mine]

Noting that highlighted element above, I'd say it's *perfect* for OP, not "a miserable little word".

Comment: Very interesting, I hadn't realised that. I'm still of the opinion that it's a bit of a miserable sounding word, but perhaps a particularly appropriate miserable word ;)

Comment: @rbennett485: I don't really see what you've got against it. Being in the "independent software producer" business myself, I know I was using ***monetize*** quite naturally over 15 years ago in the context of preliminary discussions with a guy who was later to become my business partner. Basically, he thought his role would be to tell me what to develop (on the basis that he knew what he could sell), and I thought his role should be to sell what I wanted to develop (on the basis that I knew what I could/wanted to produce). In practice, it was a bit of both, and everything worked out okay.

Answer (score 1):

**[Moneymaker](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/moneymaker)**: 
something that produces or yields much pecuniary profit.

**Revenue generator**: A revenue generator facilitates [revenue generation](http://www.ask.com/question/revenue-generation-definition).

Comment: Also *generating income* or *income generator*. Same idea.

Comment: "Income-generating" has a nice ring to it.

Answer (score 1):

Monetizable is a great word, quite often used to mean "convertible into monetary units." For example, "increased flow through an intersection is a benefit that is not just a convenience but is monetizable, as well."

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for something that means "able to produce enough money to survive", I would recommend **sustainable**, and if you want to make it more clear, **economically sustainable**.

Answer (score 0):

Credit to @bib for putting it in the comments first, but the succinct and non-jargon way of saying that you expect people to pay for the game is:

> The game will be:
>
> - **For profit.**

As opposed  to "Freemium" or "Free-to-Play", people will be expected to pay for the game. *Profitable* is another way of phrasing this, but it carries with it the assumption of preordination. (I.E. that the game will make money, rather than expected to make money.)

I don't like *monetizeable* because of the weasel-word jargon — unless it truly is expected to make money through another means besides user-pay. (Pay-to-play "freemium" models, advertising, click-throughs etc.) I don't like *revenue generator* and *moneymaker* for similar reasons: they have odd connotations.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest **earner**. Or to be more specific, perhaps **wage earner** or **[income earner](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Income_earner)**